# Jquery Mouse Events vs Z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a smaller block inside larger block.

I put an event to display a message as the mouse enters or exits the each block

Whether in or out of block does not occur error, but the event is triggered when change block to the other

```
<div class="red">
    <div class="blue">OK</div>
</div>

.red {width:200px;height:200px;background:red;position:relative}
.blue {width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.red').mouseover(function(){
        alert('in');                                      
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        alert('out');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/20gv6auu/3/

Is there any event to group all elements as a single element for jquery?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain a little more? What do you want to happen?

Comment: An event occurs when leaving the block, I don't see the problem...

Comment: Do you ask for a solution where the alert doesn't happen when you move the mouse from one block to the other?

Comment: that's exactly what I want to know totymedli

Comment: It already **[works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/mw58750s/)**, just don't use alerts because they mess with the mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper div and use that to trigger the event with `mouseenter();` instead.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="red">
      <div class="blue">OK</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
   border: 1px solid green;
   width: 200px;
}
```

JS `(use mouseenter();`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrap').mouseenter(function(){
        alert('in');                                      
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        alert('out');
    });
});
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/JYmvom)

Comment: When you move from block to another the event is triggered. I want to prevent this happening

Comment: fixed, use mouseenter with the wrap.